# How i can get Process.waitForFinish()

Tags: c#, .net, process, signals

I'm trying to get the pid of a process when the process end working but not yet killing.

```
process.WaitForExit();
```

the method above stop until the process is killed, but i'm looking for something like `process.waitForFinish` because i'm trying to handle the process when it finishing working but not yet killed.

Like adding a signal and get in the other process. exemple:

```
//Process to catch
main(){
    //Do some Code
    End of the function
    SendEndSignal(); & Stop();
}
```

Second process will catch first process like that

```
main(){
    int pid = Process.start("Process1.exe");
    process.waitUntilReceiveSignal();
    //Do code here
    process.kill();
}
```

I need something like `process.WaitForInputIdle();` but the problem here is it working only if the process contain graphical interface. So what about if the process wait for input from user by console like using `Console.readLine()`.

This mean that i need to know when the process go to inactive state but not killed.

Comment: Unfortunately no. it use just process.WaitForExit();

Comment: Unfortunately, if you don't have control over how the target process finishes, there is no reliable way to determine when the process has finished it's 'work'.

Comment: @MrPaulch that's why i'm thinking about sending endsignals from process to process but don't know how to do it

Comment: Check for the process is idle. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2784881/how-to-check-if-process-is-idle-c-sharp

Comment: @MusakkhirSayyed i see that it's an heuristic approach, and the programm will work constantly trying to checking if the process is idle or not yet. so it will consume lot of cpu usage

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`EventWaitHandle` is a way to go in your case.

```
namespace A
{
   class Program
    {
       static void Main(string[] args)
        {
           var evh = new EventWaitHandle(false, EventResetMode.AutoReset,"fromA");
           Console.WriteLine("Anykey to send signal");
           Console.ReadKey();
            evh.Set();
        }
    }
}

namespace B
{
   class Program
    {
       static void Main(string[] args)
        {
           Console.WriteLine("Waiting for a signal");
           var evh = EventWaitHandle.OpenExisting("fromA");
            evh.WaitOne();
           Console.WriteLine("Signal!");
           Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

But keep in mind you will need to wait for child process to register its `EventWaitHandle`. So you either do wait for some time (ugly). Or create another `EventWaitHandle` in parent process, so child process notifies when its handler is registered

**Edit:** Complete solution

```
namespace Parent
{
   class Program
    {
       static void Main(string[] args)
        {
           using (var childReadyEh =new EventWaitHandle(false, EventResetMode.AutoReset,"childIsReady"))
            {
               Process.Start("child.exe");
                childReadyEh.WaitOne();
            }

           using (var childSignalEh =EventWaitHandle.OpenExisting("childSignal"))
            {
                childSignalEh.WaitOne();
            }

           Console.WriteLine("Signal is recieved");
           Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}

namespace Child
{
   class Program
    {
       static void Main(string[] args)
        {
           EventWaitHandle childSignalEh =null;
           using (var childReadyEh =EventWaitHandle.OpenExisting("childIsReady"))
            {
                childSignalEh =new EventWaitHandle(false, EventResetMode.AutoReset,"childSignal");
                childReadyEh.Set();
            }
           Console.WriteLine("Anykey to send a signal to parent");
            Console.ReadKey();

            childSignalEh.Set();
            childSignalEh.Dispose();

           Console.WriteLine("Signal is sent");
           Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It give me error On Programme B No handle of the given name exists.

Comment: Yeah, please read my edited answer. Basically, you need to run A, then B. in that order.  As far as i got you have defined order of execution, but still need to add some synchronization out there

Comment: Yes that's what i did i run B which it will run A using Process.Start() then i Use EventWaitHandle.OpenExisting("fromA"); evh.WaitOne(); but give me error

Comment: the problem is raised here var evh = EventWaitHandle.OpenExisting("fromA");

Comment: if i run it manualy A then B it work good but if i want that the B will Run A and then wait for the signal it gives error

Comment: It's fixed by adding a sleep(1000) in the B programm thanks a lot :)

Comment: so just tell me... can process A run process B and can process B run process A. Or one is always parent and another is child?

Comment: but their in any other way without sleep ?

Comment: A is a child of B. Just B can Run A.

Comment: I've added solution without ugly sleeps. Check it out